# Google App Script Regex - trying to find but omit characters

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have a string (called numBody) I need to pull numbers out of, while leaving other numbers in place.  The string has many of the following inside it:

```
</span>510<br /> //one number I need to pick up
(60–122)         //two more I need to pick up
>361–423<br />   //I need to AVOID this one
```

I've put together a chain of regex that will do it, but it leaves me with some extraneous characters by virtue of the fact that Google Apps Script doesn't support lookbehind and I haven't figured out how to omit a character:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(">[0-9]{1,4}(?=<br)|\\([0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,4}(?=\\))", "g");
var numMatch = numBody.match(pattern);
```

So I set up my expression to pick up any group of 1-4 numbers after a > and before a br, which works to pick up the first number and avoid the numbers in the 3rd example, like I want, BUT it leaves me with the result:

```
>510
```

My second expression works like I want to pick up a number after an opening parentheses, but leaves me with:

```
(60
```

My third one includes the necessary lookforward to avoid getting any extra bits with it, so it's fine.

I tried using capturing and non-capturing structures, but that didn't work:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("(?:>)([0-9]{1,4})(?=<br)|\\([0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,4}(?=\\))", "g");
var pattern = new RegExp(">([0-9]{1,4})(?=<br)|\\([0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,4}(?=\\))", "g");
//both still return the same >510
```

In this singular expression, how can I omit that first character, given the problem that I need it to match but I don't need it in my result?

Comment: Make sure your regex has a capturing group around the pattern you need to get and use it with the `RegExp#exec` in a loop

Answer (score 0):

So, with @Wiktor's help up there, I got it to work using the following code:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(">([0-9]{1,4})(?=<br)|\\(([0-9]{1,4})|([0-9]{1,4})(?=\\))", "g");
var skillMatch = [[], [], []];
var i = 0;
var k = 0;
while((result = pattern.exec(skillBody)) !== null) {
  result.reverse();
  safeLabel:
  for(var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
    if (result[j]) {
      skillMatch[k][i] = result[j];
      break safeLabel;
    }
  }
  i++;
  if (i===3) {
    i = 0;
    k++;
  }
}
```

The exec thing creates null values for every single search piece in that long pattern that *doesn't* match at the same time it creates values for pieces that do match.  The last piece that has non-null data is the piece I need, so I had to reverse the result, iterate through it (yes, I could've just j-- but ... no), and store the first thing I got that isn't null.

Anyway, this works perfectly.